# Net::HTTPResponse body as IO

Tags: ruby, http, io

Net::HTTPResponse's body is a stream-like object, and you get can read its input in lazy chucks using read_body. In the rest of ruby, steams are represented as class IO. Is there a wrapper or something that lets me use a Net::HTTPResponse as if it was an IO object?

Comment: me too.  just today i have a need to stream an HTTPResponse to a CVS::Reader.  If i get something functional, even if ugly, i'll post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use the OpenURI library that comes with standard Ruby.   It uses Net::Http  under the hood, and provides a convenient File-like object.

```
require 'open-uri'
open('http://example.com/some_file') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    puts "http line: #{line}"
  end
do
```

Comment: If the content-length is above a certain size, this will write to disk first (Tempfile) and then yield the Tempfile IO object. Just an FYI in case disk-space is a constraint or the desire was for streaming without buffering on disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using Threads (maybe only safe in MRI), I've used this with some success:

```
# create an writable IO to write the response to 
# and a readable IO to return / yield to the caller
read_io, write_io = IO.pipe

write_io.binmode
read_io.binmode

# in a separate thread, continue adding chunks to the writable IO,
# which is connected to the readable IO we return
Thread.new do
  begin
    # pipe chunks to the write stream
    # response is the Net::HTTPSuccess object
    response.read_body { |chunk| write_io << chunk }
  ensure
    write_io.close
    Thread.current.exit
  end
end

# yield a readable stream while the thread feeds the writable
yield read_io
```

We create a read IO and a write IO that are connected with `IO.pipe`. Since `read_body` is a blocking operation that will yield to the block we give it until the whole body is done (whole content in memory), we need to `read_body` in a separate thread. As chunks are received, they are forwarded to our `write_io`. The `write_io` is essentially a proxy, but we can read from the `read_io` in a lazy fashion without waiting for the whole response body to be downloaded. This is useful for streaming parsers and perhaps your use case, too. CSV accepts an IO and can be lazily parsed with this method like so:

```
CSV.new(io).to_enum
```

Which would give you a lazy enum of csv rows.